# Image Segmentation Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-morphology

I have this BW image:

[image: Mask Object Connected]

And using the function RegionProps, it shows that some objetcs are connected:[image: Region Props]

So I used morphological operations like imerode to separte the objects to get their centroids: [image: Objects separated] 
[image: Centroids]

Now I have all the centroids of each object separated, but to that I lost a lot of information when eroding the region, like you can see in picture 3 in comparison with picture 1. 
So I was thinking if is there anyway to "dilate" the picture 3 till get closer to picture 1 but without connecting again the objects.

Comment: You are asking us how to do the last picture you have? well, there it is, you showed it. What else do you need? The last one kind of seems to have all the information you need. If you want to get the area of the different circles, I suggest you try to fit a ellipse to each of your circle centers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at bwmorph(). With the 'thicken', inf name-value pair it will thicken the labels until they would overlap. It's a neat tool for segmentation. We can use it to create segmentation borders for the original image.

bw is the original image.
labels is the image of the eroded labels.

```
lines = bwmorph(labels, 'thicken', inf);
```

[image: Image of segmentation lines]

```
 segmented_bw = bw & lines
```

[image]

You could also skip a few phases and achieve similiar results with a marker based watershed. Or even better, as the morphological seesaw has destroyed some information as seen on the poorly segmented cluster on the lower right.

Comment: I already tried watershed but it wasnt showing the result that I wanted. But with the morphological operation thicken it gives me some positive results. In some cases erase some information, but I will work it out with this method. Thank you for your usefull idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each white pixel in the mask to the closest centroid and work with the resulting label map:

```
[y x]= find(bw);  % get coordinates of mask pixels
D = pdist2([x(:), y(:)], [cx(:), cy(:)]);  % assuming cx, cy are centers' coordinates
[~, lb] = min(D, [], 2); % find index of closest center
lb_map = 0*bw;
lb_map(bw) = lb; % should give you the map.
```

See [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) for more information.